# Polymer App Hosting on Firebase - API Keys exposed when Source is Viewed

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-hosting

I created a Polymer App and I want to deploy it to Firebase Hosting. Most of the documentation I followed puts the Firebase initialization code on the `index.html` file.

Things like the API key get exposed on <kbd>View Source</kbd>. Is there a better way to implement this and keep the API keys hidden?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing, have you made any progress with this?

Answer (score 0):

The API Key is used to identify your Firebase project. Don't worry about that the key is exposed to user.

Read more:

- [Is it safe to expose Firebase apiKey to the public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public)
- [How to restrict Firebase data modification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418143/how-to-restrict-firebase-data-modification)