# Is it good to expose my firebase data structure in client code?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I create a web app with the serverless client-firebase model, it seems almost 100% my data structure, comprises of nodes, subnodes, duplicate nodes and key:values, is exposed by those DB ref URLs, CRUD and atomic update functions from client js code .

I am not saying that I am not gonna put DB rules, but to only question that exposing so much info which client does not need at all, is it beneficial to hackers only?

I am thinking of create a REST API in the middle and hide firebase queries, but this somehow against the serverless idea.  is Cloud Functions for Firebase a cue here?

P.S. I have read related questions below, but they are not the same.

- [How to restrict Firebase data modification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418143/how-to-restrict-firebase-data-modification/35419194#35419194)
- [Is it safe to expose Firebase apiKey to the public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public/37484053#37484053)

Comment: You seem to have a knack for opinionated questions. :-)   I often recommend that you model your View Model from an MVVM architecture in Firebase. If you do that, it makes complete sense that your app sees this data structure. In fact: the whole reason the view model exists is to show it in the app.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, sorry that I dont quite follow you here, could you please share more information. Do you mean by using MVVM architecture, it is not a problem anymore to expose firebase data structure?