# password based authentication in Firebase is secure or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Let me explain first what approach I am using while implementing that web chat
When user signup on my website, I create his account on firebase using following things

1. email: user email password
2. List item

---

when User sign in next time I pass user email and own created password to firebase to signin him to firebase too. and then whole process for the chat begins.

Now I have one question that our apiKey, authDomain, databaseURL, storageBucket are already exposed in javascript code and we are again exposing email and password  in javacript code for signing the user in firebase. **so isn't a loophole?**

I hope you got my point so please if I am doing it wrong kindly guide me to how to use it properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesnt that belong to *Informational Security*?

Comment: These are just identifiers that are needed to find your project on the Firebase servers. See stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public

Comment: Yes I found my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418143/how-to-restrict-firebase-data-modification. thankyou for your support