# how to restrict request from other domain in firebase database

Tags: security, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

After reading  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38860737/9315896) ,I followed same step but I can still access my firebase database of first project from other project domain using config of first project.

[image]

Comment: The answer you linked only describes how to limit sign-in to users coming from a specific domain. It does not limit access to the realtime database. Have a look at this answer for a more likely approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943350/how-do-i-lock-down-firebase-database-to-any-user-from-a-specific-email-domain

Comment: Yeah,you are right. I misunderstood.