# Firebase API key restriction not working with Android app package name and SHA1 fingerprint

Tags: android, firebase, security, crashlytics, api-key

We are using Google Firebase to get CrashLytics data for our app, and the API key that is exposed through the `google-services.json` file was brought up as a security concern as the app apk file can be reverse engineered to get this file and then it can be used by an attacker to send data to our Firebase account.

To avoid this, we tried to follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys?authuser=1) to restrict the API key usage such that it can only be used by our app. This is achieved by restricting it with the package name and the SHA1 fingerprint of the keystore of our app.

However when we tested it out, it didn't work as expected. We were still able to send crash data via a fake app that has the same package name, same `google-services.json` file but a different keystore file.

Based on the accepted answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418143/how-to-restrict-firebase-data-modification), this approach should work. Appreciate it a lot if anyone with experience on this can share with us.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: No. Back then we gave up on this approach. It's been some time already. Not sure if any new changes have occurred in Google Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis, and in your project credentials you'll see that your APIs are unrestricted. Follow the on-screen instructions on each API to restrict them.