# FireBase + React : How to access api keys stored in Google Cloud inside Firebase app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an application that uses Firebase as a backend and use third party tools achieve data.

Instead of configure the external API keys in firebase code(which will be visible in browser), I a trying to configure them in my Firebase projects google cloud console in
`https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project={MyFirebaseProject}` to use them securely.

I configured my keys GCP, but not sure how to access them in Firebase.
Is it a good and achievable solution?
I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restrict Firebase data modification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418143/how-to-restrict-firebase-data-modification)

Comment: Not exactly. I am not sure about how to access the same in my firebase code.

Comment: I think I have to use cloud functions to get this done like
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/email-confirmation/functions/index.js

Comment: But cloud functions may not help in every scenario since I might need other keys in code like google map key to render etc.. I would like to know how can I handle that scenario

Comment: I believe there is some misunderstanding on how to work with Firebase in general. Please describe your use case from the user perspective first, then we will find how Firebase can work for you.