# Firebase Invalid api key error in Next js

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, api-key

I am just making a sign up page using Next JS. I am using Firebase as backend.

My code which, I  want to work :-

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: `${process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY}`,
    authDomain: `${process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN}`,
    projectId: `${process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID}`,
    storageBucket: `${process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE}`,
    messagingSenderId: `${process.env.FIREBASE_MSG_ID}`,
    appId: `${process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID}`
  };
  
  // Initialize Firebase
  const APP = initializeApp(firebaseConfig, "Demo App");
  const AUTH = getAuth(APP)
```

But its not working. 
 Error:-
`FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/api-key-not-valid.-please-pass-a-valid-api-key.).`

My code which works:-

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_My_Api_Key`,
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  };
  
  // Initialize Firebase
  const APP = initializeApp(firebaseConfig, "Demo App");
  const AUTH = getAuth(APP)
```

**Note :-**

- **This project is open source and I don't want to expose my api keys.**
- **I know, I can use NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY but this exposes api keys on the source of dev tools.**
- **Their is no typo in the name of environment variable.**

Comment: Have you tried logging the values in the firebaseConfig object to your dev console, they might be undefined or not what you are expecting.

Comment: @FavourFelixChinemerem Yes, they all are undefined.

Comment: Any suggestions to fix it. Thanks

Comment: I think this is a great place to start: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Is it safe to expose Firebase apiKey to the public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public)?

Comment: @juliomalves Thanks.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418143/how-to-restrict-firebase-data-modification
I got to know about google cloud api. I must use it.